# How to write select statement with if statement in where coundition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to write one select statement in postgres how could I place if condition in where condition

To creating a report in that suppose we have 20 country in our table and and we have three type of employee which having `contact, payroll and permanent` these are the employee_category I would like to get all employee details except `India` and `USA` who having contact employee in these two country if employee having payroll and permanent should come in result

something like this

```
SELECT
r.employee_id AS E_ID,
r.Joining_date AS J_DATE,
r.employee_type AS E_TYPE,
'NIL'::text AS REMARKS,
i.source as SOURCE,
i.user_orgname as USER_ORGNAME
from master_employee r
INNER JOIN users_master AS i ON r.user_id = i.loginid and  i.userstatus = 'Active' 
WHERE 
if(country="india","USA"){
employee_category!='contract'
}
 and
date(r.createddate) = date(now())
ORDER BY r.createddate ASC ;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: I'm using  PostgreSQL

Comment: Gordon's answer is right but you may prefer: `where not (country in ('india', 'USA')
and employee_category = 'contract') and ...`

Comment: I'm creating a report  in that suppose we have 20 country in our table and and we have two type of employee which having contact, payroll and permanent these are the  employee_category  i would like to get all employee details except `India` and `USA` who having contact employee in these two country if employee having payroll and permanent should come in result @George query is working but the 215 record is missing

Answer (score 2):

Using the case statement should work.

```
SELECT
r.employee_id AS E_ID,
r.Joining_date AS J_DATE,
r.employee_type AS E_TYPE,
'NIL'::text AS REMARKS,
i.source as SOURCE,
i.user_orgname as USER_ORGNAME
from master_employee r
INNER JOIN users_master AS i ON r.user_id = i.loginid and  i.userstatus = 'Active' 
WHERE employee_category <> case when country in ("india","USA") then 'contract' end
 and date(r.createddate) = date(now())
ORDER BY r.createddate ASC ;
```

Comment: The implied `else` in your `case` expression will evaluate to null and then the comparison will fail. Not sure what OP wants here exactly. Of course the error is the result of using double quotes.

Comment: I'm creating a report  in that suppose we have 20 country in our table and and we have three type of employee which having contact, payroll and permanent these are the  employee_category  i would like to get all employee details except `India` and `USA` who having contact employee in these two country if employee having payroll and permanent should come in result @George query is working but the 215 record is missing

Answer (score 1):

Instead, use basic boolean logic:

```
where (country not in ('india', 'USA') or
       employee_category <> 'contract'
      ) and
      date(r.createddate) = date(now())
```